# Running 32 bit userland on Redhat

Tags: linux, redhat, 64-bit, 32-bit, library

I have a third party python API thats only available in 32 bit (ELF 32-bit LSB shared object) that I need to run on a x64 RedHat server. Of course this doesn't work smothly since the python installation is 64 bit. I figure that the way to solve this is to run python as 32 bit userland on the 64 bit kernel.

How do I do this? Do I have to compile a 32 bit python on RedHat x64? Is there an easier way?

# cat /etc/redhat-release 
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Client release 5.3 (Tikanga)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to easily install a 32-bit redhat chroot and run your python from that. You can use [Mach](http://thomas.apestaart.org/download/mach/) to generate the chroot, then just chroot into the directory that you built with Mach and run your script from there.

More information can be found:

- http://www.psg.com/~brian/howto/mach.html
- http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/UsingMach